# Unable to deserialize JSON data into a List<T>

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

If *candles.json* does not exists or it exists and the first element's start date and the last element's end date are different, it will serialize the data to `List<IBinanceKline>` and create *candles.json*. If *candles.json* exists, it should read it and deserialize the data into `List<IBinanceKline>`. Right now, it is only unable to `DeserializeObject<List<IBinanceKline>>` with the following error message:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Binance.Net.Interfaces.IBinanceKline' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
> Path '[0]', line 1, position 2.'

The funny thing is that the code used to work before they updated the library and now it uses IBinanceKline instead of BinanceKline.

candles.json looks like so:

```
[[1598918400000,0.02916000,0.02933000,0.02805000,0.02840000,160360176.00000000,1598920199999,4581586.82491700,8467,65052915.90000000,1858526.79404600,0.0],[1598920200000,0.02841000,0.02875000,0.02832000,0.02867000,58358821.40000000,1598921999999,1666101.98325900,3117,22117012.60000000,631314.89648100,0.0]]
```

```cs
List<IBinanceKline> candlesFromFile = null;
if (File.Exists(CandlesFile))
{
    var content = File.ReadAllText(CandlesFile);
    candlesFromFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IBinanceKline>>(content); // Exception thrown here
}

List<IBinanceKline> candles;
if (candlesFromFile != null && candlesFromFile.First().OpenTime == StartDate && candlesFromFile.Last().OpenTime == EndDate)
{
    candles = candlesFromFile;
}
else
{
    candles = GetCandlesByStartDateEndDate(symbol, interval, StartDate, EndDate);

    string serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(candles);
    File.WriteAllText(CandlesFile, serializedObject);
}

private List<IBinanceKline> GetCandlesByStartDateEndDate(string symbol, KlineInterval interval, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    if (endDate.Date > DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The end date is greater than today.");

    var candles = _client.Spot.Market.GetKlines(symbol, interval, startTime: startDate, endTime: endDate, limit: 200).Data.ToList();

    while (endDate > candles.Last().OpenTime)
    {
        var moreCandles = _client.Spot.Market.GetKlines(symbol, interval, startTime: candles.Last().OpenTime, endTime: endDate, limit: 1000).Data.ToList();
        candles.AddRange(moreCandles.ExceptUsingJsonCompare(candles));
    }

    return candles;
}
```

```cs
public interface IBinanceKline
{
    DateTime OpenTime { get; set; }
    decimal Open { get; set; }
    decimal High { get; set; }
    decimal Low { get; set; }
    decimal Close { get; set; }
    decimal BaseVolume { get; set; }
    DateTime CloseTime { get; set; }
    decimal QuoteVolume { get; set; }
    int TradeCount { get; set; }
    decimal TakerBuyBaseVolume { get; set; }
    decimal TakerBuyQuoteVolume { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your JSON is a `List<List<something>>`, not a `List<something>`, which is basically exactly what your error message tells you.

Comment: @oerkelens, actually it says that `GetCandlesByStartDateEndDate` returns `List<BinanceSpotKline>`

Comment: would it deserialise to a list of an interface? I feel there is a need for a concrete class to deserialise

Comment: I'm not talking about your code, I'm talking about your JSON. It starts with `[[` and ends with `]]`, which makes it an array of arrays, or a `List<List<something>>`. That will never deserialize into a `List<something>`.

Comment: @oerkelens, in fact, it used to. I see what the problem is. While I'm serializing it, it serializes it to `List<BinanceSpotKline>` while it's trying to deserialize it to `List<IBinanceKline>`. BinanceSpotKline has an additional property.

Comment: You can write own converter for this.

Comment: To top it up without a converter it will not know which properties to match too.

Comment: Your json is nothing more than a list of a list of numbers. Not sure how you can deserialize to your object class

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I posted the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comments, the problem occurred because `List<IBinanceKline>` doesn't really specify which class it will serialize to. In fact, it did serialize to `List<BinanceSpotKline>` instead.

Solution:

```cs
List<BinanceSpotKline> candlesFromFile = null;
if (File.Exists(CandlesFile))
{
    var content = File.ReadAllText(CandlesFile);
    candlesFromFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BinanceSpotKline>>(content);
}

List<BinanceSpotKline> candles;
if (candlesFromFile != null && candlesFromFile.First().OpenTime == StartDate && candlesFromFile.Last().OpenTime == EndDate)
{
    candles = candlesFromFile;
}
else
{
    candles = GetCandlesByStartDateEndDate(symbol, interval, StartDate, EndDate);

    string serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(candles);
    File.WriteAllText(CandlesFile, serializedObject);
}

private List<BinanceSpotKline> GetCandlesByStartDateEndDate(string symbol, KlineInterval interval, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    if (endDate.Date > DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The end date is greater than today.");

    var candles = _client.Spot.Market.GetKlines(symbol, interval, startTime: startDate, endTime: endDate, limit: 200).Data.ToList();

    while (endDate > candles.Last().OpenTime)
    {
        var moreCandles = _client.Spot.Market.GetKlines(symbol, interval, startTime: candles.Last().OpenTime, endTime: endDate, limit: 1000).Data.ToList();
        candles.AddRange(moreCandles.ExceptUsingJsonCompare(candles));
    }

    return candles.Cast<BinanceSpotKline>().ToList();
}
```